# Convert integer into percentage

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, percentage, plsqldeveloper

I don't know how to convert integer into percentage,  please help me. Thank you

Here's the query:

```
SELECT 'Data' || ',' ||
       TO_CHAR(D.DTIME_DAY,'MM/dd/yyyy') || ',' ||
       NVL(o.CNT_OPENED,0) || ',' || --as cnt_opened
       NVL(c.CNT_CLOSED,0)           --as cnt_closed
  FROM OWNER_DWH.DC_DATE d
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT TRUNC(t.CREATE_TIME, 'MM') AS report_date,
                    count(*) AS cnt_opened
               FROM APP_ACCOUNT.OTRS_TICKET t
               WHERE t.CREATE_TIME BETWEEN SYSDATE -120 AND SYSDATE
               GROUP BY TRUNC(t.CREATE_TIME, 'MM')) o
    ON d.DTIME_DAY=o.REPORT_DATE
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT TRUNC(t.CLOSE_TIME, 'MM') as report_date,
                    count(*) AS cnt_closed
               FROM APP_ACCOUNT.OTRS_TICKET t
               WHERE t.CLOSE_TIME BETWEEN SYSDATE -120 AND SYSDATE
               GROUP BY TRUNC(t.CLOSE_TIME, 'MM')) c
    ON D.DTIME_DAY=c.REPORT_DATE
  WHERE d.DTIME_DAY BETWEEN SYSDATE -120 AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) -1 AND
        d.DTIME_DAY = TRUNC(d.DTIME_DAY, 'MM') AND
        TRUNC(d.DTIME_DAY,'MM')= d.DTIME_DAY
  ORDER BY D.DTIME_DAY;
```

The output of that query:

```
 Data,10/01/2013,219,201
 Data,11/01/2013,249,234
 Data,12/01/2013,228,224
 Data,01/01/2014,269,256
```

example output that I need is like this:

```
 Data,10/01/2013,219, 52%, 201, 45%
 Data,11/01/2013,249, 75%, 234, 60%
 .......
 ........
```

Formula:

```
create_time + close time = total / create_time (for cnt_opened each column) = percentage
create_time + close time = total / close_time (for cnt_closed each column) = percentage
```

Comment: can you please show the formula to find the percentage?

Comment: percentage = part / whole ...so `count(*)` is your part?

Comment: i already a formula @MaheswaranRavisankar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Basically just add the total of CNT_OPENED and CNT_CLOSED, then whichever you want to take the percentage of, multiply that by 100 and divide by the sum.

For instance, CNT_OPENED = 219 and CNT_CLOSED = 201 so the total is 420. Multiply CNT_OPENED by 100 and then divide by 420 -> (219 * 100) / 420 = 52. Do the same thing with CNT_CLOSED.

Note that this WILL result in an exception if both CNT_OPENED and CNT_CLOSED are 0.

```
SELECT 'Data'
||','||TO_CHAR(D.DTIME_DAY,'MM/dd/yyyy')
||','||NVL(o.CNT_OPENED,0) --as cnt_opened
||','||(NVL(o.CNT_OPENED,0) * 100) / (NVL(o.CNT_OPENED,0) + NVL(o.CNT_CLOSED,0)) || '%'
||','||NVL(c.CNT_CLOSED,0) --as cnt_closed
||','||(NVL(o.CNT_CLOSED,0) * 100) / (NVL(o.CNT_OPENED,0) + NVL(o.CNT_CLOSED,0)) || '%'
```

That will also potentially give you a million decimal places, so  if you only want to take it out to a couple, simply use the TRUNC function and specify your precision (2 decimal places in this case):

```
TRUNC((NVL(o.CNT_OPENED,0) * 100) / (NVL(o.CNT_OPENED,0) + NVL(o.CNT_CLOSED,0)), 2)
```

Comment: Remember to include the `'%'` as well.

Comment: Now, how can i get the percentage without cnt_opened column? Like, i just want to get only the cnt_closed? and i don't want to display the cnt_opened? @Joel

Comment: You will still have to have the data in your from in order to have the full count to calculate the percentage, but if you don't want to display it, simply remove it from the select clause. It would end up as SELECT 'Data'
||','||TO_CHAR(D.DTIME_DAY,'MM/dd/yyyy')
||','||NVL(c.CNT_CLOSED,0) --as cnt_closed
||','||(NVL(o.CNT_CLOSED,0) * 100) / (NVL(o.CNT_OPENED,0) + NVL(o.CNT_CLOSED,0)) || '%'